# canvas draw causing NaNs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a line using `ctx.lineTo` in loop.

I have small function in my prototype

```
this.draw = function(ctx)
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    trace(trail.join(' '));
    for(var i=0;i<trail.length;i++)
    {
        // ctx.lineTo(trail[i].x,trail[i].y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

When I run this, I receive some points traced (`[389.272, 722.798] [392.583, 25.069]...`) but I see nothing (very surprising)

When I remove the comment from `ctx.lineTo`, it fails and my trace returns `[NaN, NaN] [NaN, NaN]...`. Constants in drawing function works perfectly (and my points doesn't change), but I need value from variables...

What's wrong? Problem occurs only on Firefox

edit:
trace is simple text assignment to html object
trail is an array of points which are simple objects

```
function point(x,y)
{
    this.x = x;this.y = y;
    this.toString = function()
    {
        var xs=this.x.toFixed(3);
        var ys=this.y.toFixed(3);
        var xs="     ".substring(0,8-xs.length)+xs;
        var ys="     ".substring(0,8-ys.length)+ys;
        return "["+xs+","+ys+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: So the trace differs when you uncomment that line?

Comment: yes, i can't access "trail" in any "ctx.*" drawing function.

Comment: What is in the "trail" object?  Seems like that's kind-of important ...

Comment: Try using a `moveTo` once in the beginning to the first point, does that help?

Comment: You also haven't shown what "trace()" does.

Comment: trail is an array of "point" objects which contains this.x, this.y and simple toString method. trace is document.getElementById("trace").innerHTML = text;
 
@pimvdb nothing changes

Comment: It would be strange that `trail` changes if you pass it as an argument to `lineTo`. Are you sure you aren't calling anything else?

Comment: I'm sure. Array changes smoothly without lineTo, nothing bad happens. I have only 2 assigns, one in constructor and one per tick in other method (which works perfectly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's still not enough information to really answer this, so I'm going to just hazard a guess: change the "point" constructor as follows:

```
function point(x,y)
{
    this.x = x - 0; this.y = y - 0;
    this.toString = function()
    {
        var xs=this.x.toFixed(3);
        var ys=this.y.toFixed(3);
        var xs="     ".substring(0,8-xs.length)+xs;
        var ys="     ".substring(0,8-ys.length)+ys;
        return "["+xs+","+ys+"]";
    }
}
```

The idea is to make sure that "x" and "y" are actually **numbers** and not strings. You could also do this:

```
    this.x = x - 0; this.y = y - 0;
    if (isNaN(this.x) || isNaN(this.y)) {
      alert("NaN! NaN!  x is " + x + "  y is " + y);
```

Comment: @Frizi OK, well, unless you post more code or supply more details, I doubt anybody will be able to help. However I'll modify my answer with one more suggestion.

Comment: ok, i find my faulting call. It was division by 0 in temporary code... thanks.